# Why submit input by clicking the enter button not work on mobile phone browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, htmx

I got a strange problem. I want to search for a product by clicking enter button. I used `e.which == 13 || e.which == 10` with `keypress keyup` trigger, like below.

```
<form id="fform" method="get" autocomplete="off" action="/search">
<div class="search-inner-container">
    <button @if(isListing) { id="buttonSearchTextListing" } aria-label="unf-search-btn" type="submit"
        class="search-button search-keyword" value="Search"></button>
    <input
            style="cursor: text;"
        @if(isListing) {
            form='fform'
            onclick="!this.form && document.getElementById('fform').submit()"
            name="srp-searchText"
        } else {
            name="srp-searchText"
        }
        id="searchbar-top"
        autocomplete="off"
        type="searchText" class="searchbar-text search-input bt1 @uuid" aria-label="Search"
            value="@text" placeholder='@l("searchBar.buttonLabel")'
                hx-get="/search-autocomplete"
                hx-vars="'srp-userInput': getSearchbarVal()"
                hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:500ms"
                hx-target=".searchbar-suggestion-container"/>
                <!-- hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:500ms, focus changed delay:500ms" -->

</div>
</form>
```

```
$('.searchbar-text').each(function(){
    $(this).on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13 || e.which == 10) {
            // code
        }
    });
})
```

I've tried this on my laptop browser (chrome & Mozilla Firefox). I tried with the element inspector on the desktop/mobile display, it works fine. But when I try it on a mobile phone browser, it doesn't work. When I press enter, it jumps to another section and does not submit the form. This only happens on the product search page on mobile phones but on other pages, it works fine.

*I tried to debug the clicked keyCode on alert when on the homepage it appears the keyCode is 13, but when in product search the alert keycode doesn't appear

if you want to try, just test from a website that I've developed [HERE](https://www.daruma.co.id/search?srp-searchText=grinder), and try in the desktop - mobile phone browser to search (e.g saw) and click enter

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Not sure what this is, I know what it isn't - HTML

Comment: Jon P blade syntax, for example, includes the use of @if for inline if-statements and it’s all HTML at the core, there’s another language used that is not tagged but you should look at Laravel’s HTML and also Ionic’s HTML amongst others and you’ll see how it has evolved in other languages/libraries/frameworks

Comment: this is htmx @JonP

Comment: @RelebohileNkosi, it's not HTML at the core. It's something else that renders HTML. What it is, is important, many frameworks (angular, vuejs etc) recomend **against** using jquery, knowing exactly what we are dealing with is important when it isn't plain old html. For example how does `hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:500ms"` interact with `$(this).on("keyup keypress"`??

Comment: i tried your website on my mobile's (android) browser and its working fine for me already. i was able to search by pressing enter key on mobile's keyboard. I think you should add an alert on keypress on your development server and then try it with the mobile with which its not working for you to make sure if that mobile is sending the same key code you are expecting.

Comment: can you send a screen record of the steps you have do? I've tried adding an alert when I press enter, and the mobile phone alert doesn't appear @FarzBhullar

Comment: https://ufile.io/lnqapc0j here it is. @frankfurt

Comment: @frankfurt i am also confused that why are you using both keypress and keyup events at same time ? and also why you using each function if you can bind the event to selector directly ? like $('.searchbar-text').on("keyup", function (e) { if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 10) { // code here } }

Comment: ahh yeah, from the homepage it's normal and it can works well. But try on the page whose link I have provided in the post above. @farzbhullar

Comment: Is it a problem when combining 2 events? and why I use each is because in 1 page there are 2 searchbars, specifically for desktop and mobile @farzbhullar

Answer (score 2):

Simply set `type='submit'` to the button and set display none. Make sure to wrap the input field and the button in form tags. Then handle the submit.

```
<form>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Search for an item'>
  <button type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i've the button with ```type="submit"```. THis is my button => ```<button aria-label="unf-search-btn" type="submit" class="search-button search-keyword" value="Search"></button>```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

using `UIEvent.which` seems to be a "non-standard." Use `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` instead.
Also, the reason "type=submit" didn't work is because you used it on a `<button>` element. They are not technically "input's," so you can use `type` on it.

If you try using an `<input>` element, it should work perfectly fine. Something like this should work:

```html
<input aria-label="unf-search-btn" type="submit" class="search-button search-keyword" value="Search"/>
```

Then assuming you have the `<form>` element set up, it should work fine.

Comment: I have the form. but why does this only happen in mobile phone browsers? If I use inspect element with mobile view it works. So it's hard for me to debug it. And many people recommend using ```e.which```instead of ```e.keyCode```

Comment: That's incorrect, e.which is worse than e.keyCode. You can see on MDN that e.which is non-standard and shouldn't be used as there are better alternatives. Also, the problem could be that e.which doesn't work on mobile browser (which I doubt), or that the keycodes are a little different. Try using an `<input>` element with `type=submit` instead. Your problem should be instantly fixed. (if so, remember to accept the answer)

Comment: are you sure to add type in the input? because if i'm doing that, if I want to fill in the input it will be submitted directly can't input anything

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. When you add "type=submit," it becomes a submit button

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Are you sure? Show me your code.

Comment: i've add the input element on the post above

Comment: You need to set the `<form>` node up. It has 2 main attributes. The `method` attribute, which is either `GET`, `POST`, etc... and the `action` attribute, which is the URL you want to send the request **to**. Whenever you have an `<input>` with a `name` attribute, it will send that `name` attribute with the value of the given input. For example: having an input with the name 'hello' and it's text being 'isuajhd' would send a GET request (if set to GET) of http://link/path?hello=isuajhd

Comment: i have form tag, i have edit post above

Comment: Make sure you don't have any invisible items on top of the button.

Comment: [The `<button>` element has a `type` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the OP has an invisible element above the `input`/`button` element.

Comment: Set the `<input>`'s z-index to 9999999. (in CSS)

Comment: @frankfurt you don’t have to use input, the same button tags do accept the “type” attribute that f submit.

Comment: so button shouldn't have a type attribute? @gre_gor

Comment: I'm just trying to give an example of the suggestion from Battledosh to give the type attribute to the input @RelebohileNkosi

Comment: The button needs the type attribute. But add `z-index: 9999999` to the CSS of the button/input

Comment: @frankfurt I know, I'm just referring to those suggestions that says <button type="sbumit"></button> must be changed to <input type="submit"/>... that's pointless because both of them are the exact same thing since they serve the same purpose.

Comment: I was unaware of that, sorry for the confusion. You are apparently fine to use `<button type="submit"></button>`. But let me know if the z-index thing worked. If so accept the answer

Comment: I prefer not to go to random links, sorry

Comment: no, that's the website that i develop. and the problem is there @Battledoosh

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working exactly you want in my mobile, try putting `return false;` on input submit

```
$('.searchbar-text').each(function(){
        $(this).on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13 || e.which == 10) {
            console.log('Submitted');
            }else{
            console.log(e.which);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Seriously? Can you record your step?

Comment: i have added ```return false;``` and still not working

Comment: don't return false because if you do so, this will prevent to type anything in the search box

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add `e.preventDefault()` as well. Edit: and then `$("#fform").submit()`.

Comment: if i do that, there'sno action right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think then you'd also submit the form.